# How to create a zero-filled variable without mentioning the batch size

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

If I have a tensor (let's call it `src`) of shape `(?, 10)` I can create a zero-filled variable of the same shape like this:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
zeros = K.zeros_like(src)
```

But if I don't have a `src`, how can I can create a similar variable? I've tried this and failed:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
zeros = K.zeros(shape=(None, 10))
```

Comment: Would `K.zeros_like(K.placeholder(shape=(None, 10)))` work?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHa, thanks but it seems this does not work with TF2. Do you have a solution that works with TF2 as well?